# Do new UIViews created inside TableViewCell delete by themselves when cell deleting?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiview

According to my last question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46686134?noredirect=1). Since I created a view inside the cell as separator, my other view controllers button messed up and I can't seem to solve it.

The question is: If I create a new UIView inside a UITableViewCell and then delete that cell from the app, does the UIView created inside it still remain present? Do I have to delete it somehow or it deletes by himself, since I added the view to the cell.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "delete that cell". You can remove a row from the table, but cells (UITableViewCell instances) are *never* "deleted" — they are reused. It is up to you to reconfigure every cell before it is reused. If you put a view into a cell for a certain row, and you don't want that view present if that cell is reused in another row, it is up to you to remove the view from the cell.

Comment: Matt, I was going to say that there's no such thing as deleting cells, but thought that might cause confusion since there is a method to remove specific rows from a table view. The cells that you remove don't get deleted, they get put in the reuse queue, but the method name is `deleteRows(at:with:)`.

Comment: Cells aren't rows.

Comment: Understood. But the call does tell the table view to remove cells at those specific indexPaths. The cells aren't destroyed, but they are removed from the table view. The distinction is a tad hard to explain to a beginner.

Comment: I think we _did_ explain it. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, views do not delete themselves from cells. When you delete cells, or they scroll off-screen, they get added to the recycling queue. The next time you call `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath)`, you may get that cell returned to you, including views you added to it.

In general it's better to set up your cells with all their views as part of the cell prototype. That way you dequeue a reusable cell and it has all the views you need, and no extras. If some cells need to have different numbers of views, create a new template for those cells with a different identifier and dequeue one of those cells instead.

Alternatively, you could set up your cell prototype to create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell with (weak) outlets for your extra views that are nil initially. Then if you add those views hook up their outlets. Finally, when you dequeue such a cell, check those outlets and remove any non-nil views as part of setting up the cell for reuse.

Comment: Is there any way possible for a view to still remain there if I created it by code, removed the code to create the view & reinstalled the app ?